# Safe parallel use of MVector/IOVector from Haskell vector package

Tags: haskell

Can I safely assign to non-overlapping indices of an IOVector (from the Haskell vector package) from multiple parallel threads, or do I need an additional mutex?

Background: I want to run a collection of IO computations in parallel and then record all the results.  I started by returning the results in a list, but this seems like the wrong data structure.  So I am looking to use an IOVector from the vector package to store the results.

My question is, can I write something like:

```
runPar :: [IO a] -> IO (IOVector a)
runPar tasks = do
  v <- new (length tasks)
  mapM forkIO [task >>= write v i | (i, task) <- zip [0..] tasks]
  -- Wait for all tasks to complete
  return v
```

Is this guaranteed to be safe?  Or do I need to have a mutex-like control (e.g. holding v in an `MVar`) to make sure that only one write proceeds at a time?

Comment: If that doesn't work it should really be a bug. You could also consider passing a `Chan` to your tasks and read the results as they're produced if that's appropriate for your application.

Comment: The reason why a vector fits here is that I want the results to be in the corresponding order as the tasks (which may complete at different rates), but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The documentation indicates that `IOVector` is `MVector RealWorld` and `MVector` is just a `MutableByteArray`. The tutorial on arrays (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Welcome_to_the_machine:_Array.23.2C_MutableArray.23.2C_ByteArray.23.2C_MutableByteArray.23.2C_pinned_and_moveable_byte_arrays) says that `MutableByteArray` is just like a C array. Would you expect that writing to different indices of a C array from different threads would be unsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code and the discussions in the comments, there seems to be no reason to assume it is not thread-safe. And just to support this, here is a little test for it:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as V
import System.Environment
import Control.Concurrent.Async

thread v i 0 = return ()
thread v i n = do
    x <- V.read v i
    V.write v i $! x-1
    thread v i (n-1)

main = do
    [m,n] <- map read `fmap` getArgs
    v <- V.replicate m n
    tis <- mapM (\i -> async (thread v i n)) [0..m-1]
    mapM_ wait tis
    r <- mapM (V.read v) [0..m-1]
    if all (== 0) r then putStrLn "OK" else putStrLn $ "Not OK: " ++ show r
```

Here, even with 100 threads spawned in parallel, counting down from 1000000, with `-RTS -N` or `-RTS -N10`, always yields `OK`.